# Sorting not working in ubuntu

Tags: server, sort

I am running sorting script for existing file on ubuntu using bowl script:

```
sort -r -k 2 -o mayflies.txt
```

but terminal hangs and not showing anything, however it works without -o but i need to sort in the file and not on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given any input file on which the `sort` operation will place, thats why the terminal is waiting for the input on STDIN. This is because as if you have not provided any input file, `sort` will take the input from STDIN.

What you need is, e.g. if the input filename is `foo.txt` :

```
sort -r -k 2 -o mayflies.txt foo.txt
```

This will save the sorted output of `foo.txt` into `mayflies.txt`. If you omit the `-o mayflies.txt` portion the sorted output will be shown on the screen (STDOUT).

On the other hand, if your input and output filenames are meant to be the same file i.e. if you want to save the output to the same file :

```
sort -r -k 2 -o mayflies.txt mayflies.txt
```